# How can I override behat tests Feature Context in Oro?

Tags: behat, orocrm, orocommerce

I've updated login form in Oro application so that now behat tests cannot login to application using 'Given I login as AmandaRCole@example.org buyer'.

The problem is that in this Feature Context (\Oro\Bundle\ApplicationBundle\Tests\Behat\Context\CommerceMainContext) it searches for 'Email Address' and 'Password' form inputs, however these form inputs now have another names. How can I override this context for our needs, or how can I change approach to make tests green?

Comment: The easiest way - create a BehatExtension (that is CompillerPass) and replace all CommerceMainContext in each suite by your custom inherit Context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login step implemented in [OroMainContext](https://github.com/oroinc/platform/blob/53421e85c2793531a592cd98d947a5fefbf481b6/src/Oro/Bundle/TestFrameworkBundle/Tests/Behat/Context/OroMainContext.php#L717)
It's implicitly or explicitly (e.g. [OroUserBundle suite](https://github.com/oroinc/platform/blob/53421e85c2793531a592cd98d947a5fefbf481b6/src/Oro/Bundle/UserBundle/Tests/Behat/behat.yml#L133)) by `behat.yml` configuration injected in each test suite.
Selectors `_username`, `_password` and `_submit` are hardcoded in the `loginAsUserWithPassword` method.

You can either replace OroMainContext with your inheritor in all behat suites by BehatExtension, see `Behat\Testwork\ServiceContainer\Extension`, or you can rewrite `Oro\Bundle\FormBundle\Tests\Behat\Element\OroForm` and do your dirty hack there, because this class will fill the form. Don't forget to rewrite the class for `OroForm` element in your behat.yml

The right way, I guess, will be to create a Login from, extended from `OroForm` that should be used in `OroMainContext`. This form will have method `fill` that accept two arguments `login` and `password`. In this case, you will have rewrite only this tiny element to change the flow. But, I also guess, it's a long way to do so.